# Private network same dsl phone line?

Tags: networking

Shouldn't I be able to connect a second router to my existing phone line with a dsl filter and have a separate wireless network to connect to and monitor? I want to use the existing netgear 7500 just as it is for the front portion of our property wich isn't good enough signal in the back for Internet anyway and and use a netgear 7550 connected to same phone line with filter for Internet access with separate password. What is the best way to go about doing this? Is this a VPN? I am going to be using up to six devices on the second router.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't hook two DSL modems to the same phone line (the same copper pair) and have them talk to each other or have them both talk to the ISP's DSLAM (the ISP end of a DSL modem connection).

If you have a second copper pair (like a "line 2", even if currently unused) then you may have options like HomePNA. Or you could get a second line of DSL service on that second line, but then you'd have to set up a VPN between the two routers so that your front and back devices can talk to each other.

Otherwise you'll need to look at wireless extension (WDS), pulling Cat5e or better cable for Ethernet (fiber if the run is more than 100 meters), MoCA if you already have coax, or power line networking like HomePlug AV2 or G.Hn, etc.